# How to create select all checkbox for all the checkboxes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to create a checkbox that selects and deselects all the checkboxes in python.

Getting the checkbox entry:

```
var0 = IntVar()
var1 = IntVar()
var2 = IntVar()
var3 = IntVar()
var4 = IntVar()
var5 = IntVar()
var6 = IntVar()
var7 = IntVar()
var8 = IntVar()
var9 = IntVar()
var10 = IntVar()
```

Creating the Checkboxes assign the variables:

```
chkNewHire = Checkbutton(master, text="New Hire", variable=var1).grid(row=1, sticky=W)
chkAddrChange = Checkbutton(master, text="Address/Demographic Change", variable=var2).grid(row=2, sticky=W)
chkRateChange = Checkbutton(master, text="Rate Change", variable=var3).grid(row=3, sticky=W)
chkTerm = Checkbutton(master, text="Termination", variable=var4).grid(row=4, sticky=W)
chkSwtUpdate = Checkbutton(master, text="SWT Update", variable=var5).grid(row=5, sticky=W)
chkW4Update = Checkbutton(master, text="W4 Update", variable=var6).grid(row=6, sticky=W)
chkDirDepos = Checkbutton(master, text="Direct Deposit/PayCard Update", variable=var7).grid(row=7, sticky=W)
chkPayCard = Checkbutton(master, text="Pay Card Update", variable=var8).grid(row=8, sticky=W)
chkEmplTransNewSto = Checkbutton(master, text="Employee Transfer working only in new store", variable=var9).grid(row=9, sticky=W)
chkEmplTransBothSto = Checkbutton(master, text="Employee Transfer working only in both stores", variable=var10).grid(row=10, sticky=W)

#Create a list to assign the select all button - work on fixing the select check button
chkList=[chkNewHire,chkAddrChange,chkRateChange,chkTerm,chkSwtUpdate,chkW4Update,chkDirDepos,chkPayCard,chkEmplT ransNewSto,chkEmplTransBothSto]

Checkbutton(master, text="Select All", variable=var0, command=chkList).grid(row=0, column=1)
```

Comment: Please [edit] the code in your question and provide a runnable [mre] showing your own attempt to accomplish this.

Comment: This is what I have

Comment: What you currently have is incomplete — it can't be run because too much has been left-out. On the other hand, it's also not "minimal" in the sense that there appear to be many more `Checkbutton`s being created than absolutely necessary to demonstrate what's desired. Lastly FYI, the universal widget `grid()` method always returns `None`, so your `chkList` is going to end-up just being a bunch of `None` values.

Comment: This is all I have for my check boxes I think i need a function to  use for the select all checkbox and deselect

Comment: Thanks can you help me please?

Comment: A runnable tkinter application will generally include a call to `tkinter.Tk()` to initialize the module as well as one to `mainloop()` to run the GUI created. Also "minimal" in this case would only require having two or three `Checkbutton`s, not 10 of them…

Comment: My window shows all 10 of my checkboxes and they all work individually

Comment: Perhaps it's a language issue, but you do not seem to understand what I have been trying to convey — all that is needed and desired in questions here is the _least amount of code_ that demonstrates the issue / or causes the problem to occur, not your whole program with lots of redundant or irrelevant stuff in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have chained `Checkbutton(...)` with `grid(...)` when creating those checkbuttons, then all the variables (`chkNewHire`, `chkAddrChange`, etc) are `None`.  You should separate the statement into two statements, like:

```
chkNewHire = Checkbutton(master, text="New Hire", variable=var1)
chkNewHire.grid(row=1, sticky=W)
```

Second you assign `chkList` (a list) to `command` option of `Select All` checkbutton is incorrect, you need to assign a function reference instead.

In order to select and deselect all the checkbuttons, you can use `select()` and `deselect()` function on all the checkbuttons.

Below is an updated code based on yours:

```
chkNewHire = Checkbutton(master, text="New Hire", variable=var1)
chkNewHire.grid(row=1, sticky=W)

chkAddrChange = Checkbutton(master, text="Address/Demographic Change", variable=var2)
chkAddrChange.grid(row=2, sticky=W)

chkRateChange = Checkbutton(master, text="Rate Change", variable=var3)
chkRateChange.grid(row=3, sticky=W)

chkTerm = Checkbutton(master, text="Termination", variable=var4)
chkTerm.grid(row=4, sticky=W)

chkSwtUpdate = Checkbutton(master, text="SWT Update", variable=var5)
chkSwtUpdate.grid(row=5, sticky=W)

chkW4Update = Checkbutton(master, text="W4 Update", variable=var6)
chkW4Update.grid(row=6, sticky=W)

chkDirDepos = Checkbutton(master, text="Direct Deposit/PayCard Update", variable=var7)
chkDirDepos.grid(row=7, sticky=W)

chkPayCard = Checkbutton(master, text="Pay Card Update", variable=var8)
chkPayCard.grid(row=8, sticky=W)

chkEmplTransNewSto = Checkbutton(master, text="Employee Transfer working only in new store", variable=var9)
chkEmplTransNewSto.grid(row=9, sticky=W)

chkEmplTransBothSto = Checkbutton(master, text="Employee Transfer working only in both stores", variable=var10)
chkEmplTransNewSto.grid(row=10, sticky=W)

#Create a list to assign the select all button - work on fixing the select check button
chkList = [
    chkNewHire, chkAddrChange, chkRateChange, chkTerm, chkSwtUpdate,
    chkW4Update, chkDirDepos, chkPayCard, chkEmplTransNewSto, chkEmplTransBothSto
]

def toggle_all():
    for cb in chkList:
        if var0.get():
            cb.select()
        else:
            cb.deselect()

Checkbutton(master, text="Select All", variable=var0, command=toggle_all).grid(row=0, column=1)
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my mistakes. @acw1668